# What does this formula stand for?

Tags: microeconomics

W/Vmp = ? I think it is the marginal product....but I have really no clue....any help on this?

Comment: Are you sure this isn't W=Vmp? W/Vmp should equal 1...

Comment: I dont know man, I really dont....

Comment: Is this a homework question where they're asking you to figure out what W/Vmp equals?

Comment: Why on Earth would you want to know the meaning of a formula without knowing anything about the context?

Answer (score 1):

$W$ = Wage

$VMP$ =Value of Marginal Product

When $W/VMP$ <1, workers generate more value than they cost to pay. Hire more workers.

When $W/VMP$ >1, workers generate less value than they cost to pay. Hire less workers.

Therefore when $W/MVP$ = 1 you are purchasing your optimal amount of labour.